# Adding element to dictionary inside object inside dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 100 Cluster objects, the clusters have several Member objects and I need to add them to the Cluster they belong, my problem is that every Member es being added to every Cluster, and I can't find out why. Here's the code

```
self.clusters = {}

with open('/tmp/numpy_dumps/kmeansInput.txt.cluster_centres') as f:
    for line in f:
        cluster = Cluster(line)
        self.clusters[cluster.id] = cluster

with open('/tmp/numpy_dumps/kmeansInput.txt.membership') as f:
    for line in f:
        member = Member(line, self.reps)
        self.clusters[member.clusterId].members[member.imageId] = member

for id, cluster  in self.clusters.items():
    print(cluster)
    print(cluster.members)
    print('cluster {} has {} members'.format(id, len(cluster.members)))
```

The output tells me that every cluster has all the members

Comment: You should show the code for Cluster and Member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very certainly in the `Cluster` class, that you did'nt post in your snippet. It's a bit of a wild guess but this behaviour is typical of shared attributes, either class attributes or mutable default arguments. If your `Cluster` class looks like one of the snippets below then looks no further:

```
# class attributes:

class Cluster(object):
    members = {} # this will be shared by all instances

# solution:

class Cluster(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = {} # this will be per instance



# default mutable argument:

class Cluster(object):
    def __init__(self, members={}):
        # this one is well known gotcha:
        # the default for the `members` arg is eval'd only once
        # so all instances created without an explicit
        # `members` arg will share the same `members` dict
        self.members = members

# solution:

class Cluster(object):
    def __init__(self, members=None):
        if members is None:
            members = {}
        self.members = members
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, I'm pretty new to Python and haven't seen that yet :)

Comment: @SkarXa "that was it" - but which one ?

Comment: First one, my attribute was outside of __init__